# fetch all related table data before session of hibernate close

Tags: java, hibernate, session, struts2

I want to know about when i call a list from hibernate pojo from struts2 action after that i close the session. then control is moving to display the data in view. At the time of view related table data did not show. If i did not close the session then where can i close the session.

I want a solution or a way that specify when i fetch the list from pojo then related table data is also stored on their respective object. After the session close all data will be display on view. Please specify me also a good way to use hibernate.

Please suggest me I don't know how can i found the solution.

i have 3 tables one store students record 2nd save class information and 3rd save stream information, and i have respective hibernate pojo library of these 3 tables. now i fetch the records from struts action like this

```
try{
    StudentMasterLogic student = new StudentMasterLogic(session);
    this.students = student.fetchAll();
}catch(HibernateException h){
    System.out.println(h);
}finally{
    session.close();
}
return "students";
```

now i want to display all the records in view.

```
<td><s:property value="firstName" />
    <s:property value="lastName" />(<s:property value="studentId" />)</td>     
<td><s:date name="dob" format="dd-MMM-yyyy" /></td>
<td><s:date name="doa" format="dd-MMM-yyyy" /></td>
<td><s:property value="classId.classTitle" /></td>
<td><s:property value="stream.streamTitle" /></td>
```

because of closing the session i am not able to see classId.classTitle and stream.streamTitle. How can i display these values.(If i remove the session.close() line from action then it'll display fine.)

Please help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You might want to browse through the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) page for hints on what to include in your questions, and what not to ask. :)

Comment: can we guess your code?

Comment: Hello SIr I update the question, Please help me now

Comment: Read up on the _Open Session in View_ pattern. Also, don't try to manage a `Session` inside of an action. Instead, use something like Spring or at least a `Filter` or `Interceptor` to manage the session lifecycle.

Comment: And yes, you need to close the session when you're finished.

Comment: Hey Steven Benitez, can you please share some example for hibernate and sruts 2.How can i implement Open Session in View pattern.